# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a problem error in my output code: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'

```
import json,requests
    
link = "https://some.com.br/api/v1/integration/customers.json"
headers = {'iliot-company-token': '3r5s$ddfdassss'}


def get_data(page):    
    Parameters = {"page": page}
    clients2 = requests.get(link, headers=headers, json=Parameters)
    lista_clients2 = clients2.json
    print(lista_clients2())

#Get it all at once
all_page_data = list(map(get_data, range(1,51)))


#If you want to make a dataframe
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(all_page_data) 
#You can also split out json-formatted data, if it's in a single column
full_df = pd.json_normalize(df[0])
```

Comment: Put a return in your `get_data` function. If this is missing it returns `None`

Comment: Also `json` is a method, not an attribute. Do `return clients2.json()`

Comment: Tks guys, it works fine, but in my "full_df" results I only get the first line of each page.

Comment: and  I'd like to break the code because sometimes I don't know how many pages the API has